I cant connect to my android device via appium inspector
Device is connected to PC, I can check it via ping and ADB devices -l.
Appium server running fine.
When trying to reach the device via appium inspector I get the following message:
'Failed to create session. An unknown server-side error occurred while processing the command. Original error: Appium Settings app is not running after 5000ms'
When checking the logs of appium server, I get the following:
[ADB] Starting Appium Settings app
[ADB] Running 'C:\Users\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe -P 5037 -s vm3_90c8e85b853 shell am start -n io.appium.settings/.Settings -a android.intent.action.MAIN -c android.intent.category.LAUNCHER'
[ADB] Getting IDs of all 'io.appium.settings' processes
[ADB] Running 'C:\Users\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe -P 5037 -s vm3_90c8e85b853 shell pgrep -f ([[:blank:]]|^)io.appium.settings([[:blank:]]|$).
I have no clue what the last log is, however I can connect to the device. Any idea what is going on? Help is much appreciated
I reinstalled appium and inspector.
Changed the software of this android device.
Device is rooted, and remounted.
However when I use another device, I can a reach it via inspector. Maybe some issue with permissions from the devices side
